# Number Of Solutions for the equation: $a^2 - b^2 = X$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Suppose there is an equation $a^2 - b^2 = X$

how many pairs of $(a,b)$ exist to find $X$, when $a,b$ and $X$ are positive integers.

It would be great if you could direct to proof although not necessary.

An example:
$a = 13, b = 11 X = 48$.

```
13^2 - 11^2 = 48
```

how many more $(a,b)$ pairs exist for 48? How to find out/them ?

I am not a Maths student although i see that this is a variant of a 'diophantine equation'?

Comment: Have you tried factoring?

Comment: No, I have not, I am not sure how to do factoring with two unknowns.

Comment: Factor the LHS and interpret *solutions* as *divisors*.

Comment: Thank you yes it helps - _ "So the number of ways we can express a natural number n as a difference of two squares is the same as the number of ways we can factor n as a product of two integers, that are both odd or both even. " _